# javascript - ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-data-grid

While checking the source of one open source project ([react data grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/packages/react-data-grid/src/editors/EditorBase.js)), I've stumbled upon this syntax which I couldn't wrap my head around:

```
class EditorBase extends React.Component {

  getStyle(): {width: string} {
    return {
      width: '100%'
    };
}
```

Especially the `getStyle(): {` part.

I've tried to consult other SO questions, MDN [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) references but didn't any mentions of the above syntax.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: https://flow.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this looks to be a usage of Flow-type (created by Facebook) which is a static type checker for Javascript. (Which you can think of like a Linter but for Data Types instead of syntax)

So the part that looks confusing may be this bit:

```
{width: string}
```

In flow, when you have a colon after the function's parenthesis, it will denote the expected type of return from that function.

This code notifies Flow that the function should return an object that has a key of 'width' that should be of type 'string'.

Check out [Flow.org](https://flow.org/en/) for more information, and how to get started using it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

The code you are referring to checks the types of variables being passed to a method.

Flow code/type checks have only use in development mode and will be stripped by babel.

> Flow is a static type checker for JavaScript.

Read more about [flow](https://flow.org/).

Here is [babel plugin](https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-typecheck) that is being used for react-data-grid. It is actually deprecated, you should instead use [babel flow-runtime](https://codemix.github.io/flow-runtime/#/babel-plugin-flow-runtime) (in case you would like to use it).